# Phasor analysis confusion in the trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry

I was learning about phasor analysis from Fundamentals of electric circuits by Alexander and Sadiku.

In chapter 9 the below trigonometric identity is given.

[image]

As per my knowledge sin is positive in the 2nd quadrant and negative in all other quadrants(ALL SILVER TEA CUPS). In the first equation Sin(wt±180) means it is lying in the 2nd quadrant and 3rd quadrant depending phase shift is +180 or -180.

When it is lying in the 2nd quadrant *(Sin(wt-180))* it should be positive and when it is lying in the 3rd quadrant *(Sin(wt+180))*should be negative.This is my understanding.

But in the book it is given as Sin(wt±180)=-sinwt .May I know where I went wrong

Comment: The sine function is positive in the first quadrant as well. How much is $\sin 45^\circ$?

Comment: Yes all functions are positive in the 1st quadrant

Comment: So if $\omega t$ is in the first quadrant (positive), adding or subtracting $180^\circ$ will get you to the third quadrant (negative). From the second quadrant (positive) you go to 4th quadrant (negative). From the 3rd quadrant (negative) you go to the first (positive). From the 4th (negative) you go to 2nd (positive). As you see, changing phase by $\pm180^\circ$ will always change sign

Comment: Thank you..now l got it we can consider +180 as anticlockwise rotation and -180 as clockwise rotation. Please correct me if l am wrong

Comment: That is correct.